# mPDF and bootstrap column on next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mpdf

I'm currently triyng to use mPDF to print a simple HTML page.
The page is done using bootstrap and it is very basic. 
Following the documentation, I can print the pdf but while in HTML everything works perfectly, in the pdf the last column is placed on the next line.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c');
$html = '<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: palevioletred;"><strong>A</strong></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: #808080;"><strong>B</strong></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: #008000;"><strong>C</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('./css/bootstrap.css'), 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
$mpdf->Output();
```

The expected output should be:
[image: expected output]

but instead the pdf is like this:
[image]

Any idea of why is this happening? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Does it help to remove the container and use <div class="row-fluid"> instead of <div class="row">?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a work-around, but have you tried assuming the maximum column width is 10? I have found that rather than the sum of the columns being 12 (your example 2 + 4 + 6), if you assume 10 (2 + 3 + 5) the layout is pretty good.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-left">
            L
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 text-center">
            <h3>Hello</h3>
            <h4>World?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-right">
            R
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I've found the same workaround (which sometimes works sometimes doesn't), but I don't want to change all my layouts to match the 10 columns. I have instead found the bug causing this issue in the mPDF code, but the author seems not interested in answering to my mails to correct it.

Comment: You're correct of course... who needs workarounds. I've switched to wkhtmltopdf as the renderer - works faster. It took me a few tries to realize the css links in the header need full base urls for it to apply the css. I highly recommend it.

Comment: @Salv0 did you post your patch somewhere, like on GitHub or such? We're looking after the same issue, and we're having troubles finding a solution. thanks

Comment: @Maxxer hey, no at the time I wrote it there was no Github repo. I will do it later today or tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

I think i found another work around that worked for me.

```
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>

    </div>
```

Try using all the col class available.

Comment: weirdly enough this solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

this works for me-

first, remove all paddings

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-xs-4" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px"> 
</div>
<div class="col col-xs-4 text-center"  style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px"> 
</div>
<div class="col col-xs-4 text-right"  style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The mPDF docs explain why these Bootstrap column wrapping problems exist:

https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/floating-blocks.html

> Note: The width that is set defines the width of the content-box. So
>   if you have two floats with width=50% and either of them has padding,
>   margin or border, they will not fit together on the page.

In Bootstrap 3, the columns are floated, with `.row` having `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `-15px`, and `.col-{x}` has `padding-left` and `padding-right` of `15px` to space them out.

So my solution for the OP example is to remove the Bootstrap margins and padding as below:

```
$bootstrapCss = file_get_contents('./css/bootstrap.css');
$customCss = '
.row {
    margin-left: 0; 
    margin-right: 0; 
}

.row .col-xs-1, .row .col-xs-2, .row .col-xs-3, .row .col-xs-4, .row .col-xs-5, .row .col-xs-6, .row .col-xs-7, .row .col-xs-8, .row .col-xs-9, .row .col-xs-10, .row .col-xs-11, .row .col-xs-12 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}';

$combinedCss = $bootstrapCss . $customCss;

$mpdf->WriteHTML($combinedCss, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
```

Note that if you write your styles using `WriteHTML($styles, 2)` you won't be able to use any other `<style>` tags in your HTML.

This works for my use case as I don't need the spacing of the col padding - but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><?php echo $this->title; ?></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right"><?php echo $this->date; ?></div>
</div>
```

Override some bootstrap css for PDF:

```
.row {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important; 
}

.row > div {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

or if **.row > div** is not working (for me it didn't), add some class (eg "col") to column divs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-4"><?php echo $this->title; ?></div>
    <div class="col col-xs-4 text-center">2</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-4 text-right"><?php echo $this->date; ?></div>
</div>
```

and use

```
.row .col {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For pdf's, along with having margins forced mostly to 0, I also reduce the width of each col by 0.5%, then everything fits nicely.

One way to do this is to include custom col classes in html:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-p-2">
```

And define them in the css file that is being used with MPDF:

```
.col-p-2{ width: 16.16666667%!important; } /* normal col-2 is 16.66666667% */
```

Here's the classes if anyone needs them:

```
.col-p-1{width: 7.83333333%!important;}
.col-p-2{width: 16.16666667%!important;}
.col-p-3{width: 24.5%!important;}
.col-p-4{width: 32.83333333%!important;}
.col-p-5{width: 41.16666667%!important;}
.col-p-6{width: 49.5%!important;}
.col-p-7{width: 57.83333333%!important;}
.col-p-8{width: 66.16666667%!important;}
.col-p-9{width: 74.5%!important;}
.col-p-10{width: 82.83333333%!important;}
.col-p-11{width: 91,16666666%!important;}
.col-p-12{width: 99.5%!important;}
```

Edit:

Another, 100% accurate way, is to generate table(s) instead of using cols. This is the most reliable method if you have complex grid with new rows inside cols, multiple rows in multiple containers and you need to make sure the columns are 100% in line, and so on.

For MPDF you already (hopefully) define size of the print area, for example for A4: `width: 21cm; height: 29.7cm;`, so you can simply divide that width into corresponding fixed column widths:

For A4, `col-6` would be `(21 / 12) * 6 = 10.5cm` and so on. Then you can use these fixed width values for tables, tr's, th's and td's, and the end results will be 100% accurate, without the float issues you get with multi-level bootstrap grid.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but I had the same problem and this was the only solution I found

First we Override the bootstrap :

```
.row {
margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important;
padding: 0px !important;
}
```

a then we set the columns like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">TEST</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">TEST</div>
</div> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">TEST</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">TEST</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">TEST</div>
</div>
```

the columns in the pdf look great so far